# Restrict Code Analysis suppression?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, azure-devops

We have recently implemented the use of Code Analysis.

**Is it possible to restrict users from suppressing Code Analysis results to In Source?**

I only want suppressions to be stored in the suppression file (`GlobalSuppressions.cs`).

[image]

Our projects are hosted on TFS (on Visual Studio Online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using a custom check-on policy.
See how to [create](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx) and [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492668.aspx) it.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. If a team member can edit the file then he's free to add any code he likes, including the SuppressMessageAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom code analysis rule to detect any `SuppressMessageAttribute` instances applied against anything other than the module or assembly.